# Dependent field - Any declarative approach?

Tags: fields

I have a requirement to show/hide a lookup relationship field in new opportunity page when the campaign equals a certain value. If that was a VF page, I can do it with render attribute. But since new Opportunity has multiple layouts for different record types, it might be too expensive to so many VF pages. Is there any alternative way to achieve this? It doesn't have to be show/hide, just anything similar (like greyed out) is also okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another "dodgy way" of doing that by using the home page sidebar messages component and write some javascript code that will change the CSS of that field or completely remove the element from the DOM. Though, this is not recommended and I've heard that this sidebar component hack will soon come to an end, SF will apparently prevent javascript code from executing. Apart from that your only option would be a custom VF override page I suppose.